# DotNet Core 3.1 - Multiple projects with shared src, obj and bin

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I have the following folder structure (following the feature-oriented organization):

```
Solution
  bin
  obj
  src
    Module1
      Shared.cs
    Module2
      Shared.cs
    Module3
      Shared.cs
    Server
      Program.cs
      Startup.cs
    Database
      Program.cs
  Solution.sln
  Server.csproj
  Database.csproj
```

For the `Server` project I am using `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` and `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` for the `Database`.

Here is the actual `Server.csproj`:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>NetCoreApp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Development</Configuration>
        <EnvironmentName>$(Configuration)</EnvironmentName>
        <BaseOutputPath>bin/$(MSBuildProjectName)</BaseOutputPath>
        <OutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)/$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
        <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>obj/$(MSBuildProjectName)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
        <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)/$(Configuration)</IntermediateOutputPath>
        <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>False</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
        <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>False</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
        <EnableDefaultContentItems>False</EnableDefaultContentItems>
        <Nullable>Enable</Nullable>
        <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
        <RootNamespace>OeMis.Server</RootNamespace>
        <StartupObject>OeMis.Server.ServerEntry</StartupObject>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="Configuration.$(Configuration).json" ExcludeFromSingleFile="True" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.30"/>
        <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate" Version="11.0.0-preview.95"/>
        <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore" Version="11.0.0-preview.95"/>
        <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="11.0.0-preview.95"/>
        <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Playground" Version="11.0.0-preview.95"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.0.0-preview1.20021.1"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Import Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" Project="Sdk.props"/>
    <Import Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" Project="Sdk.targets"/>
</Project>
```

And here is the `Database.csproj`:

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>NetCoreApp3.1</TargetFramework>
        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Development</Configuration>
        <EnvironmentName>$(Configuration)</EnvironmentName>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <BaseOutputPath>bin/$(MSBuildProjectName)</BaseOutputPath>
        <OutputPath>$(BaseOutputPath)/$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
        <BaseIntermediateOutputPath>obj/$(MSBuildProjectName)</BaseIntermediateOutputPath>
        <IntermediateOutputPath>$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)/$(Configuration)</IntermediateOutputPath>
        <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>False</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
        <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>False</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
        <EnableDefaultContentItems>False</EnableDefaultContentItems>
        <Nullable>Enable</Nullable>
        <RootNamespace>OeMis.Database</RootNamespace>
        <StartupObject>OeMis.Database.DatabaseEntry</StartupObject>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Include="Configuration.$(Configuration).json" ExcludeFromSingleFile="True" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.30"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="2.0.0-preview1.20021.1"/>
        <PackageReference Include="Bogus" Version="29.0.1"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Import Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" Project="Sdk.props"/>
    <Import Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" Project="Sdk.targets"/>
</Project>
```

I always get errors in `src/Server/Program.cs` as if `Database.csproj` is trying to handle it. The errors have to do with missing references classes in `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`.

The full project can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/geekox86/OeMis)

Answer (score 0):

This actually makes sense. You are trying to build the same source files with different dependencies.

My advise is to extract the common/shared items from both and add the to a new project called shared (preferable in .Net standard) and reference the libraries in both your projects.

[Creating a class library for .net core guide here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-a-net-core-class-library/)

TL;DL;

1. Create a Solution and Client App.
2. Create a Class Library Project.
3. Add Class Library Functionality.
4. Settings.
5. Build.
6. Add Class Library Reference.
7. Import Namespace.
8. Call Functions.

Comment: Thank you Athanasios. Will be able to have all csproj files in the root folder and share src folder for their classes?

Comment: You will have one project per folder, but you will be able  to use the classes everywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me because I want to organize all projects files by feature, so I can have a feature folder with files from multiple projects. Is it possible to achieve such setup?